# Unable to Load Candidates on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I can't get the candidates to load; it continues to spin. I paid $500 to search candidates and I can't. What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked the [Careers Support](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/support) page?  All I can see there is an email address and a phone number, but I don't have an employer account so I might not be able to see everything.

Answer (score 6):

Everything should be back to normal now.  Thanks for the report and our apologies for the inconvenience.